# Error: 'I didn´t find a database entry for "X"'

Tags: bibtex, errors, citing

I seem to have a beginner problem with setting up and executing LaTex (other posts did not help)

When I try to compile i get the error: [image]

I think I have done everything right in my code:

```
\documentclass[1pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
Hello World \cite{de1992methods}. 

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{mybib.bib}

\end{document}
```

And in the same folder here is my mybib.bib file

```
@article{de1992methods,
title={Methods to measure properties of slow-scan CCD cameras for electron detection},
author={De Ruijter, WJ and Weiss, JK},
journal={Review of scientific instruments},
volume={63},
number={10},
pages={4314--4321},
year={1992},
publisher={AIP Publishing}
}
```

Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. You seem to have done a copy-paste error or something, the second `\bibliographystyle` should of course just be `\bibliography`. And you should not include `.bib` in there.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you very much. I really did not see this :D of course now it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by a simple syntax mistake (using `\bibliographystyle` instead of `\bibliography` and including `.bib` after name of bibfile).